# laravel ajax returns whole object of joined table

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I just want to get name from table users but it returns the whole user object in network tab which leaks private information like phone (which is just in users table)

Admin Model:

```
class Admin extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['name'];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->user?$this->user->name:'';
    }
}
```

Admin Controller:

```
    public function ajaxLoadAdmins (Request $request)
    {
        $query = Admin::select('admins.slug', 'admins.about')->paginate(10);
        return $admins;
    }
```

bur when I call this function form ajax/axios it return a whole user object along with name which contains all columns of users table

I also tried by not using accessors/mutators and did it as simple as the following code but still it has a user object when we see in network tab of devtools or if we log in it in console...

```
  public function ajaxLoadAdmins (Request $request)
    {
        $query = Admin::select('admins.slug', 'admins.about', 'users.name')->leftjoin('users','admins.user_id','=','users.id')->paginate(10);
        return $admins;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Laravel` includes can be clunky, extra unnecessary columns and sometimes multiple duplicate models if one to many relationship is involved. Use with instead, it will eager load your relationship and transform it on the response.

```
Admin::with('user')->paginate(10);
```

Your admin model will have this structure and your username will be included with minimal effort.

```
{
    "slug": "admin",
    "about": "interesting",
    "user": {
        "name": "John doe"
    }
}
```

You can hide transformed properties on you model. So on your User.php model add the following.

```
class User {
    protected $hidden = ['phone'];
}
```

Comment: already tried

this is the structure of your answer

{
    "slug": "admin",
    "about": "interesting",
    "user": {
        "name": "John doe",
         "phone":"03000000000"
    }
}

Comment: And the name is there?

Comment: oh you want to hide the phone? i update my answer

Comment: i want to hide phone just in this single query,

Comment: return DB::table("tablename")->select("fieldname","fieldname")->paginate(10)

Comment: try using with('user:id,name'), but your whole approach seems weird, you often want similar structures, but here you want something unique.